# Component Lifecycle methods are not invoking when calling index.html in React js

Tags: reactjs, exec-maven-plugin

i have integrated a node app into existing Spring MVC project using exec-maven-frontend plugin and calling index.html from dist folder using ajax call, call goes inside and runs my sagas but does not invoke component life cycle methods of react component and hence not rendering the page.

```
        axios({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/reactapp/dist/index.html',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'text/html',
                    'Accept' : 'text/html'
            },
            data: ''
            }).then(response => {
                    return response;
                }).catch( error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    return error;
                });
```

Edit: My intention here is to be able to get the app div of my react app and append it to my existing html.

Comment: Axios will return the HTML from your `..../index.html` but it will not run the Javascript from the page.

Comment: it is actually running my sagas but response doesn't have content in app div, any workaround for the same or am i missing anything here..? my intention here is to be able to get the app div of my react app and append it to my existing html.